# Identity a subfield of ℝ that is isomorphic to fraction field of R={a+bsqrt(3)} where a, b are integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is easy to see that R is a subring of ℝ, but I don't know how to find an isomorphism between the fraction field of R and a subfield of ℝ .

My intuition is that it is isomorphic to R with rational coefficients instead of integer coefficients, is it correct?

Comment: Quotient field is confusing. Should prefer fraction field here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ is a field and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ the fraction field $\widehat{\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]}$ of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ must be contained in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$. But $\sqrt 3\in\widehat{\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]}$ where $\widehat{\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]}$ is a field containing $\Bbb Q$ and thus $$\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)\subseteq\widehat{\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]}\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\therefore\;\widehat{\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]}=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)\;\;\;\;\;$$